# Microsoft Remote Desktop Keychain access

Tags: keychain, remote-desktop

I use Microsoft Remote Desktop and have passwords saved for different remote desktop connections. Since some time back I get the error:

```
We couldn't retreieve your password from your keychain, please enter your password again.
```

[image: Screenshot from Microsoft Remote Desktop]

I've reset the Keychain inside Keychain Access Management:
[image: Screenshot from Keychain Access Management]

I've also looked for cached files in `~/Library/Caches` but didn't find any for Microsoft Remote Desktop.

I get the same problem when running Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by deleting the username/password settings from MS Remote Desktop Preferences. After adding them again, it works.

[image: Screenshot from Microsoft Remote Desktop Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue on Mac in app "Keychain access".

**So go in app "Keychain access"**(Mac may open Passwords on last OS, so be attentive)
**Found there name "Microsoft Remote Desktop" and delete it**.
[image]

Second trick, go to you name in "Keychain access" and set there "always allow .. applications" or use "allow all applications to access this item". I recommend revert back it after you will add Workspace.
[image]

**Issue gone**: 'Microsoft remote desktop wants to use "System" keychain'
[image]